# Doctrine get all entities from collection

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, one-to-many

I don't know if what I am trying is really possible. So I thought to ask it to you guys.

What I am trying to do:

- get a set of companies
- get all the users associated with the given companies

In code:

```
$companyIds = array(1,2,3);
$companies = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Company')->findById($companyIds);
dump($companies->getUsers()); // this will not work, but I like it to work
```

Where they are associated as follows:

```
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Company", inversedBy="users")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
   */
  private $company;
}

class Company
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="company")
     */
    private $users;
}
```

Comment: You should write a custom repository method for that

Comment: @EmanuelOster, you are right too. I am fiddling around to archive that. If you have a small pointer in the right direction, it will help me a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repository returns you an `ArrayCollection` of entities, not a single entity, therefore you need to access each of them separately.

This should work:

```
foreach($companies as $company) {
    $company->getUsers();
}
```

The problem with the above is that by default it will fetch (lazy load) users from database for each company in separate query (on demand when calling `getUsers`), which would be very inefficient on larger scale.

There are couple possible solution depending on your needs.

You could configure doctrine to always fetch users with companies, which is called eager fetch.

Having fetched users, you can merge ArrayCollections (and remove duplicates if needed), to achieve single collection containing all users.

Other way could be to fetch companies with users by creating sufficient DQL query in a custom method of you company's repository. If you need only users and don't need companies, then it could be a query that only fetches users without companies.

Comment: thanks for your answer! You are very right, a foreach is the way to do it. However do you have a small example in DQL? I like to see how to archive that. Because I like to write a custom function in my CompanyRepository.

Comment: Something like : `SELECT c, u FROM Company c LEFT JOIN c.users u`

Comment: Thanks @dragoste, I will fiddle around to get that working!

Answer (score 1):

You can e.g. fetch all `Comapany` entities with users with one query:

```
$companies = $em->createQueryBuilder()
  ->select('c, u')
  ->from('AppBundle:Company', 'c')
  // or left join based on you needs
  ->innerJoin('c.users', 'u')
  ->getQuery()
  ->getResult();
```

This will not result in queries when fetching company users.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in your User-Repository:

```
public function getAllUsersFromCompanies($ids)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
    $qb->leftJoin('u.company', 'c')
       ->where('c.id IN :ids')
       ->setParameter('ids', $ids)
       ->getQuery();

        return $query->getResult();
}
```

We are joining the user table with the company table here, which gives us the company for each user. Then, we filter out every user, that has the wrong company.